# Applying styles automatically to similar styled text

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013, microsoft-word-2013

I pasted some text in a new word document. I then selected some text and created a new style using 'New Style' command from Styles dialog. That created a new 'Style1' similar to the style formatting of the selected text.

What I want next, is to apply the 'Style1' automatically to all the similar formatted text in the document. How can I do this?

Comment: What's the style for the rest of the document, Normal?

Comment: No. multiple style formats are applied to the various portion of the document.

Comment: Thanks, that rules out the "find similar formatting" approach. That only works within a style. However, see my solution below using the find/replace method--that's pretty simple as well.

Answer (score 1):

You want to open the find/replace feature in Word (ctl + H) and click on "More".  With your cursor in the "Find" box, you'll see at the bottom that there is a "Format" button--select that and select the format properties that you want to search for.  You can select multiple categories (font, paragraph, etc.), but you'll have to go select the "Format" button for each new category.  Once you've got the format set up that you want to Word to look for, insert your cursor in the "Replace" box, select the "Format" button again and go to "Style".  Pick the style you want to convert everything to and that should work.  Here's a screenshot if you need an example:

[image]